# I want to know how to make a executable.Jar on blueJ

Tags: java, bluej

I am very new to programming Java and I know the basics, however I want to be able to take code that I made in BlueJ and turn it into a .Jar that will run when I double click. Again I am new to all of this so please make it as simple as you can! Thanks! (btw i have tried using the create jar file function that BlueJ has but it never works and i get the error "a Java Exception has occurred" everytime i try to run the Jar.)

Comment: [The BlueJ tutorial](http://www.bluej.org/tutorial/tutorial-201.pdf) seems to answer this question. Look at Chapter 8 "Creating stand-alone applications".

Comment: I looked at this and it has nothing new, I know how to do that but for some reason I always get the Java exception when I try to run it.

Comment: What exception are you getting, specifically?

Comment: It says "A Java exception had occurred" and that's it I don't know what else it means

Comment: Here's a [google search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?#q=a+java+exception+has+occurred+%2B+executable+jar); there seem to be a number of possibility that could explain this, see if one of them might be the case.

Comment: Do you have a manifest file with a main class directive?

Comment: I don't really know what that is sorry, I'm new to this like I said

Comment: just discovered this 5 years later, It's fun to see our beginnings!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, 1st I needed to update Java to current, and then secondly I needed to turn add this to my code:
public static void main(String[] params)